# how to solve error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 when trying mongodb compass connection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have successfully installed mongodb on my windows and its running but when i connect the connect remains for 2 minutes and then an error will pop

```
   error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
```

i have changed the ::1 to 127.0.0.1 and it worked successfully until I tried to access the .env file

Comment: So, the error in the title and text is solved? ... but you have a new error when you _"tried to access the .env file"_?  What's the full error text?  How do you try to access the file?

Comment: thanks for the concern 
i have changed the ::1 to 127.0.0.1 and remove a spare port from the .env file and my data base connection is cool
but i wish i could know why it fails to run on the default port ::1

Comment: The MongoDB server can communicate over IPv6, but it needs to be enabled (either on the commandline or in the config file) - the default is disabled.